# Jira Custom fields list of real names

Tags: vba, jira, jira-rest-api

Does anyone know if there is a list of what the custom fields equate to when calling jira via an api to bring the results back?

[image]

Comment: It would help your question to add the code you're using: we have no idea how you got to that screen shot, or even what it represents.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link worked and brought up a list of all custom fields.

https://*MY-JIRA-URL*/jira/rest/api/2/field

You also need to have your Jira open in the same browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure a way through restapi, but a workaround.

I had similar issue, so I exported JQL result with All fields which gave field names like custom_field012(SomeFieldName) then I had created a reference table with Custom_field and corresponding field name